# Include html files in an html file on a local file system?

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, template-engine, mustache

I have a help system that is completely offline, no server, using `file://`.

I have one main page, with hundreds of line of html that represent many sections of the help system. I would like to stick each section in a html file and just include it. Unfortunately it seems like this is only possible with some nifty server side include techniques, with HTML5 (which I do not want to assume my users have), or with a nasty javascript hack where you copy your html file into js files with document.write calls for every line as written about here: [Ways to include html in html](http://webdesign.about.com/od/ssi/a/aa052002a.htm).

What about something like `handlebars.js` or `mustache.js`? Can I use `templating`?

Comment: "or with a nasty javascript hack where you copy your html file into js files with document.write calls for every line" Never heard of that. Moustache or handlebars should be fine.

Comment: Using php you can just use `include "htmlfile.html"`

Comment: @Popnoodles, I included the link to where I found out about the JS hack
at:j_buckley, don't I need a server though to get php to include html in html?

Comment: @j_buckley You can't use PHP without a server.

Comment: yes, so unfortunately the PHP way is a no-go for me

Comment: You can change the chrome's shortcut to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files" so that you can load local files and then load html with ajax.

Comment: since local relative links work you can use frames or iframes to get this working on file:///, and then use css to try to cover up the fact that it's frame-based... on windows, saving the html file with .hta extension can allow you to load sibling files using js. you can also use jszip to mount a virtual folder of files in js.

Comment: Take a look at [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/), you will find it way easier than PHP and yor code can ba 100% Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want to use server-side includes, I would suggest using a static site generator (SSG).

If you are not familiar with `SSG's`, they allow you generate HTML pages from templates & includes (often Handlebars templates) and `HTML`, `Markdown`, `JSON`, or `YAML`, content using a `CLI`.

If you want to get started with an `SSG`, there are plenty of options, from [Ruby based Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/), or [Node.js based Assemble](http://assemble.io/). In my opinion, Assemble is the best option and I would highly recommend it.

Comment: "Since you don't want to use server-side includes" - There is a difference between **don't want to** and **can't**.